# Resources concerning cabling and wiring

Tags: cable, wiring

I have some rudimentary knowledge of cabling and wiring but I would like to expand my knowledge. Currently, if we need any rewiring done for our PBX system we call in contractors which is expensive. I'd like to find some resources and guides that can help with cabling and wiring. I haven't been able to find a good comprehensive guide.

Also, I'm looking for some suggestions on what types of hardware I should keep with me to help. Punchdown tools, tone generators, cable testers, etc.

Comment: You need to tell us where you are. This is a global site and the knowledge you seek will depend somewhat upon location, as rules and regulations vary greatly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize. I'm located in CA, USA so anything that concerns telephone and computer networking would be helpful to me.

Comment: For those who may not know, "CA" == "California".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most comprehensive reference is the [Information Transport Systems Installation Methods Manual.](https://www.bicsi.org/its_installation.aspx)

As for tools, I don't think there are too many you need to get started: punchdown tool, good quality RJ crimp tools ([I like this one from AMP](http://www.tecratools.com/product1249.html)), simple ethernet cable tester (just continuity and correct pairing).  Also the usual screwdrives and pliers.

Answer (score 3):

Cable ends and punchdowns:
http://www.cabling-design.com/references/pinouts/
Color coding:
http://www.cabling-design.com/references/colorcodes/
Punchdown eHow:
http://www.ehow.com/how_5113846_use-punch-down-tool.html
Tonegenerator eHow:
http://www.ehow.com/how_5054230_use-tone-generator.html
Knowing when to use this knowledge and where, well that's most of the cost of the consultants.